# Does it make sense to return a wrapper around a String with the intent of avoiding future validation?

Tags: c#, oop

Does it make sense to return a wrapper around a simple String object with the intent of avoiding future validation?

For instance, a URI is a simple String composed of multiple parts: scheme, authority, path, query, and fragment. When designing a class to represent the URI, I could expose the parts of the URI as simple String objects or possibly via an interface IUriCompontent.

```
public interface IUri
{
    IUriComponent Scheme { get; set; }
    IUriComponent Authority { get; set; }
    IUriComponent Path { get; set; }
    IUriComponent Query { get; set; }
    IUriComponent Fragment { get; set; }
}

public interface IUriComponent
{
    String Value { get; }
}
```

My thought is that after having parsed the components out of the URI, each could then be placed into an immutable, validated container. This container could then be passed around operating under the assumption that its contents represent a valid URI component, thereby alleviating any need for future validation.

Comment: Just write 10-20 "unit tests" that demonstrate to *you* expected usage of your interface/class. If you are happy with resulting code (i.e. no question on what `query.Value` means or why `scheme == path` does not complain at compile time) than go ahead, otherwise redesign... Not sure this can be answered in generally useful form.

Comment: I'm assuming the URI was just an example to go over your question, but just in case it isn't, you may want to look at the System.Uri class.

Comment: By "avoiding future validation," do you mean that any client is now free to pass around the container as if it is his?  How do you avoid "man in the middle" attacks?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I suppose this may be part of my question, but I was thinking more along the lines of validation internal to a single client. For instance, a client could create a URI and then pass around the Authority component under the assumption that it represented a pre-validated component. A String could also represent a validated component, but doesn't represent the fact that it is a validated component (if that makes sense). Either way, I see your point. I thought maybe a specialized container would allow me to get away from validating the same String every time it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make sense. In fact a URI is not a String. A URI is a concept that includes a scheme, an authority, etc. The fact that those components and the URI itself can be represented as Strings is an implementation detail of one possible implementation.

If you make your URI immutable, you only need to validate it once, plus you get [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) for free.

Of course, whether this is feasible or convenient will also depend on your app's requirements and use cases. But I think that providing a property to return the URI as a string should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll be proceeding in this direction. If nothing else, the interface should suggest to consumers that validation has (or should have) been completed. I suppose it is the job of the programmer to ensure that malicious objects are not passed under the guise of the interface.

Comment: If you don't want to allow malicious objects, you might consider declaring a sealed class instead. "Program against interfaces, not implementations" doesn't always mean using the interface language construct.